# Adding nodes using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-update

I have 2 XML files -

File1.xml

```
<Fruits>
   <F>Apple</F>
   <F>Pineapple</F>
   <F>Orange</F>
   <F>Banana</F>
</Fruits>
```

File2.xml

```
<Fruits>
   <F>Grapes</F>
   <F>Peach</F>
   <F>Watermelon</F>
   <F>Chickoo</F>
</Fruits>
```

I want to update/insert the File1.xml with the data from File2.xml so that I have File1.xml as -

File1.xml

```
<Fruits>
   <F>Apple</F>
   <F>Pineapple</F>
   <F>Orange</F>
   <F>Banana</F>
   <F>Grapes</F>
   <F>Peach</F>
   <F>Watermelon</F>
   <F>Chickoo</F>
</Fruits>
```

How to do this using XQuery/XQuery Update? I am using XML Database BaseX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using XQuery without a database context, Zorba has a file module if you want to update the content of a file. You can check it out at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/modules/expath/file.

If you are using an XML database, you can write the following update expression:
insert nodes $file2/Fruits/F into $file1/Fruits
$file1 and $file2 are depending on the kind of database you're using.

Comment: wcandillon-thanks I have upodated my question. I am using XML Database BaseX.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using [XQuery Update](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Updates):

```
insert nodes doc("File2")/Fruits/F as last into doc("File1")/Fruits
```

You can also change the database name to file names if you only stored the files on your hard disk, not as a database.